# How are the reputation points formatted?

Tags: support, reputation, design

What is the implementation of reputation points formatting used on Stack Overflow?

Like, `10000` reputation points is displayed as `10k`.

And `1000` is displayed as `1,000`.

And sometimes, it is rounded and then a `k` is added.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217197/204869

Comment: @Pang: Surprising that it hasn't yet gotten an answer. Perhaps more so that it was only asked as recently as this year.

Comment: Also related: [What reputation is needed to get the k?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91356)

Comment: I think it depends where are you looking, as in the `chat` you see users with `2.2k` reputation, for instance: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2312574/mikedidthis

Comment: I think the core problem is that it is not consistent hence nobody can really come with one definitive answer.

Comment: but computers can't be inconsistent, so there must be at least one person who can tell how it's programmed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after no one came up on this, I've found a way which replicates what SO does, approximately.

Here is the C#-code which I used and will use in my website ;)

```cs
public static string ReadableReps(int reps)
{
   return reps < 10000
       ? reps.ToString("N0") // or just N for culture specific
       : Math.Round(reps / 1000.0, 1) + "k";
}
```

Comment: Pro Tip: the `else` is redundant.

Comment: @Zaffy, why? It isn't redundant.

Comment: Well, the execution would be the same even without the `else`. Because `return` terminates the current function thats being executed.

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/19990446/823738

Comment: Just empirically from looking at the numbers in a few posts, I believe there is no decimal for users with at least 100k. So it's the full number for rep < 10k, one decimal for 10k <= rep < 100k, no decimal for rep >= 100k.

Comment: @Zaffy updated...

Comment: This changed (or broke) recently.  My 16563 should round to `16.6k`, but on posts it is currently just `16.5k`.  Seems like today or yesterday things changed.