# Reputation Summary under Profile Tab

Tags: discussion, reputation

Normaly if we cross 50+ reputation it will be round as 1 in SO in summary view under Profile tab .

If i have **2060 reputation** it will be shows as **2.1k** under profile tab (In community list).

But from yesterday onwards it shows as below.

Whats the reason ?

[image]

Comment: Its a change. Now it is rounded down. See also this comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250882/how-are-the-reputation-points-formatted#comment199097_253493

Comment: Stop looking at me.

Answer (score 0):

[This is fixed now.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256838/impact-stat-says-i-have-reached-a-thousand-thousand-people/257310?noredirect=1#comment839631_257310)

> should be properly rounding to nearest now, not just flooring it.